# How to add a rectangle to, and display an evaluation line on, a function plotted using `pgfplots`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I have the following function plotted with pgfplots:

[image]

I would like to somehow add a window as follows:

[image]

It can be just lines or have a transparent background color.

The code I am using is this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=4cm,
        width=0.6\textwidth,
        axis lines=middle,
        grid,                  % <--- added 
        grid style = {dashed}, % <--- added
        xlabel=$t$,     xlabel style={anchor=west},
        ylabel=$f(t)$,  ylabel style={anchor=south},
        xmin=-0.5,   xmax=10.5,  % <--- changed
        ymin=-0.5,  ymax=7.8 % <--- changed
        ]
        \addplot [thick,mark=*]
        coordinates { (0,0) (2,2)};
        \addplot [thick,o-, shorten <>=-2.5\pgflinewidth]
        coordinates {(2,4) (5,7)};
        \addplot [thick,mark=*]
        coordinates {(5,7) (8,3) (10,3)};    
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In addition, I would also like to know if there is a way to place this evaluation line (in green) with a dot.

[image]

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    height=5cm,
    width=0.6\textwidth,
    axis lines=middle,
    grid,                  % <--- added 
    grid style = {dashed}, % <--- added
    xlabel=$t$,     xlabel style={anchor=west},
    ylabel=$f^{\ast}(t)$,  ylabel style={anchor=south},
    xmin=-0.5,   xmax=10.5,  % <--- changed
    ymin=-0.5,  ymax=7.5 % <--- changed
    ]
    \addplot [thick,mark=*]
    coordinates { (0,0) (2,2)};
    \addplot [thick,o-]
    coordinates {(2,3) (4,3)};
    \addplot [thick,mark=*]
    coordinates { (4,3) (4.75,4) (10,7)};    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would appreciate your help!

This is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.3} %gráficas
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3,
    every mark/.append style={scale=1},
    scale only axis,
}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{shorten <>/.style = {shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=4cm,
        width=0.6\textwidth,
        axis lines=middle,
        grid,                  % <--- added 
        grid style = {dashed}, % <--- added
        xlabel=$t$,     xlabel style={anchor=west},
        ylabel=$f(t)$,  ylabel style={anchor=south},
        xmin=-0.5,   xmax=10.5,  % <--- changed
        ymin=-0.5,  ymax=7.8 % <--- changed
        ]
        \addplot [thick,mark=*]
        coordinates { (0,0) (2,2)};
        \addplot [thick,o-, shorten <>=-2.5\pgflinewidth]
        coordinates {(2,4) (5,7)};
        \addplot [thick,mark=*]
        coordinates {(5,7) (8,3) (10,3)};    
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    height=5cm,
    width=0.6\textwidth,
    axis lines=middle,
    grid,                  % <--- added 
    grid style = {dashed}, % <--- added
    xlabel=$t$,     xlabel style={anchor=west},
    ylabel=$f^{\ast}(t)$,  ylabel style={anchor=south},
    xmin=-0.5,   xmax=10.5,  % <--- changed
    ymin=-0.5,  ymax=7.5 % <--- changed
    ]
    \addplot [thick,mark=*]
    coordinates { (0,0) (2,2)};
    \addplot [thick,o-]
    coordinates {(2,3) (4,3)};
    \addplot [thick,mark=*]
    coordinates { (4,3) (4.75,4) (10,7)};    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please make the code snippets above into MWEs by adding your document preamble? That way I can compile your code with the same libraries and packages you are using, and then try to modify it to add the features you want. Also, in case you are unaware, you can use `\draw` commands inside the `axis` environment to draw whatever you want. For example, `\draw (axis cs:3,0) rectangle (axis cs:7,7);` will give you the rectangle you want.

Comment: @Rushi Sorry, I have already posted the complete code.

Comment: off-topic: why you use so ancient `pgfplots`?

Comment: @Zarko To make these graphs I was guided by a code that worked with compat in 1.3 and it helped me, if I change it to 1.9 it doesn't compile in texstudio, it comes out an error with the ticklabel.

Comment: @nkeLeAdo, recent version is 1.18. It is time to upgrade your LaTeX installation or at least `pgfplots`. TeXstudio is just editor and hasn't anything with used LaTeX installation.

Answer (score 6):

The box is easy to draw using the axis coordinate system, just use the command `\draw[red] (axis cs:3,0) rectangle (axis cs:7,7.5);`. If you want to have it filled, just use `\fill` instead.

For the evaluation line, I used the `intersections` library. Give a name to the path you want to mark the evaluation line on, by adding `name path global=myFunction` to the `\addplot` options. Then, add a phantom path that is long enough to intersect your function using, for example, `\path [name path=myEvaluation] (axis cs:5.5,0) -- (axis cs:5.5,6);`.
The rest is handled using

```
\draw [thick,green!80!black,name intersections={of=myFunction and myEvaluation,name=i}] (axis cs:5.5,0) -- (i-1) node [fill,circle,at end,inner sep=2pt] {};
```

The `name intersections={of=myFunction and myEvaluation,name=i}` option finds all intersections of the two paths `myFunction` and `myEvaluation` and names them `i-1`, `i-2`, `i-3`, etc. In this case, there is only one intersection, `i-1`. We use that to draw the evaluation line and add a node at the end to mark the circle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.3} %gráficas
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3,
    every mark/.append style={scale=1},
    scale only axis,
}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,plotmarks}
\tikzset{shorten <>/.style = {shorten <=#1, shorten >=#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=4cm,
        width=0.6\textwidth,
        axis lines=middle,
        grid,                  % <--- added 
        grid style = {dashed}, % <--- added
        xlabel=$t$,     xlabel style={anchor=west},
        ylabel=$f(t)$,  ylabel style={anchor=south},
        xmin=-0.5,   xmax=10.5,  % <--- changed
        ymin=-0.5,  ymax=7.8 % <--- changed
        ]
        \addplot [thick,mark=*]
        coordinates { (0,0) (2,2)};
        \addplot [thick,o-, shorten <>=-2.5\pgflinewidth]
        coordinates {(2,4) (5,7)};
        \addplot [thick,mark=*]
        coordinates {(5,7) (8,3) (10,3)};    
        \draw[red] (axis cs:3,0) rectangle (axis cs:7,7.5);
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    height=5cm,
    width=0.6\textwidth,
    axis lines=middle,
    grid,                  % <--- added 
    grid style = {dashed}, % <--- added
    xlabel=$t$,     xlabel style={anchor=west},
    ylabel=$f^{\ast}(t)$,  ylabel style={anchor=south},
    xmin=-0.5,   xmax=10.5,  % <--- changed
    ymin=-0.5,  ymax=7.5 % <--- changed
    ]
    \addplot [thick,mark=*]
    coordinates { (0,0) (2,2)};
    \addplot [thick,o-]
    coordinates {(2,3) (4,3)};
    \addplot [thick,mark=*,name path global=myFunction]
    coordinates { (4,3) (4.75,4) (10,7)};
    \path [name path=myEvaluation] (axis cs:5.5,0) -- (axis cs:5.5,6);
    \draw [thick,green!80!black,name intersections={of=myFunction and myEvaluation,name=i}] (axis cs:5.5,0) -- (i-1) node [fill,circle,at end,inner sep=2pt] {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output:]

Answer (score 3):

Very similar to @Rushi answer ... with some off-topic tweaks (for exercise) :-)

With use of the `arrows.meta` library beside `intersection` MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, varwidth] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.3} % far to old version ...
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,           % recent version, update your LaTeX instalation!
        width=0.6\textwidth,
    % common axis options are moved here
        axis lines=middle,
        scale only axis,
        grid,
        grid style = {dashed},
        xmin=-0.5,   xmax=10.5,
        ymin=-0.5,   ymax= 7.8,
        tick label style = {font=\footnotesize}  % <--- new
            }
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,    % <--- changed
                intersections}  % <--- new

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    height=4cm,
    xlabel=$t$,     xlabel style={anchor=west},
    ylabel=$f(t)$,  ylabel style={anchor=south},
            ]
\addplot [thick,mark=*] coordinates { (0,0) (2,2)};
\addplot [thick,
          {Circle[open, length=0pt 6, sep=0pt -3]}-]    % <--- new
                        coordinates { (2,4) (5,7)};
\addplot [thick,mark=*] coordinates { (5,7) (8,3) (10,3)};
\draw[red, thick]   (3,0) rectangle (7,7.6);
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    height=5cm,
    xlabel=$t$,            xlabel style={anchor=west},
    ylabel=$f^{\ast}(t)$,  ylabel style={anchor=south},
    extra x ticks={5.4},                        % <--- new
    extra x tick style={grid=none, text=teal},  % <--- new
            ]
\addplot [thick,mark=*] coordinates { (0,0) (2,2)};
\addplot [thick,
          {Circle[open, length=0pt 6, sep=0pt -3]}-]    % <--- new
                        coordinates { (2,3) (4,3)};
\addplot [thick,mark=*, name path=A]
                        coordinates { (4,3) (4.75,4) (10,7)};
\path[name path=B]  (5.4,0) -- (5.4,5);
\path[name intersections={of=A and B, by=AB},  % <--- new
      draw=teal, thick, dashed, -{Circle[length=0pt 6, sep=0pt -3]}]
     (5.4,0) -- (AB);
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Changes in above MWE in comparison to your MWE are marked by `% <---`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) package:

#### plot plus box

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.7,font=\scriptsize,thick]
\tzhelplines[step=2](11,7.9)
\settzdotsize{4pt}
\tzaxes[thin](-.4,-.4)(11,7.9){$t$}{$f(t)$}
\tzticks{2,4,...,10}{2,4,6}
\tzplot(0,0)(2,2);
\tzplot"AA"(2,4)(5,7)(8,3)(10,3);
\tzdot[fill=white,thick](2,4)
\tzdots*(0,0)(2,2)(5,7)(8,3)(10,3);
% box
\tzrectangle[red](2.5,0)(6.5,7.5)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### plot plus projection

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.7,font=\scriptsize,thick]
\tzhelplines[step=2](11,7.9)
\settzdotsize{4pt}
\tzaxes[thin](-.4,-.4)(11,7.9){$t$}{$f(t)$}
\tzticks{2,4,...,10}{2,4,6}
\tzplot(0,0)(2,2);
\tzplot"AA"(2,3)(4,3)(4.75,4)(10,7);
\tzdot[fill=white,thick](2,3)
\tzdots*(0,0)(2,2)(4,3)(4.75,4)(10,7);
% projection
\tzvXpointat*[teal]{AA}{5}(X)
\tzprojx[teal,dashed](X)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```